# Need to explicitly throw an exception in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

Is it required to throw an exception explicitly in the try block? What happens if I don't throw an exception in the try block?

```
try
{
    // code that throws an exception
    throw new IndexOutofRangeException;
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex)    
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

**EDIT**: Specifically, imagine the case there is code in the try block that *generates* an exception but `try` block does **not** have `throw` statement. What will happen?

Comment: If the code in the try block generates IndexOutofRange exception but I don't write "throw new IndexOutOfrangeException", what will happen?

Comment: Are you asking **1)** what happens if I throw exceptions **outside** of a `try-catch()` _or_ **2)** what happens if my `try` block is **empty** (no explicit/direct `throw` statement or code that could throw an exception indirectly)?

Comment: There is code in the try block that generates an exception but try block does not have throw statement. What will happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens if I don't throw an exception in the try block?

If you don't throw exception, and no other exception is raised, the `catch` block won't run. The code will instead skip past the catch block and continue executing anything that comes afterwards (including the `finally` block, if there is one).

> imagine the case there is code in the try block that generates an exception but try block does not have throw statement.

The catch block will still run... if and only if the **type** of exception matches the type declared by the `catch` block. Let's look at several examples. First up is this sample:

```
try
{
   double x = 1 / 0.0;
}
catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

In this case, we have code that causes a `DivideByZeroException` exception. Since this matches the type used in the `catch` block, the exception handler will run.

Next up:

```
try
{
   double x = 1 / 0.0;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

We still have a `DivideByZeroException` exception... but since `DivideByZeroException` inherited from the base `Exception` type, things are still compatible and the catch block will run.

Another one:

```
try
{
   double x = 1 / 0.0;
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

We still have a `DivideByZeroException` exception, but this time the `catch` block  is **not** compatible. In this case, *the program will crash* because of the unhandled exception (unless this exception is handled somewhere else in the program stack).

One more:

```
try
{
   double x = 1 / 0.0;
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Two `catch` blocks! The first block will not run, because it is not compatible with the `DivideByZeroException` type. However, the second `catch` block will run, because it is compatible. The exception is handled, and the program can continue.

Finally:

```
double DbyZ(double numerator)
{
    try 
    {
        return numerator / 0.0;
    }
    catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid operation");
    }
} 

...

try
{
     DbyZ(1.0);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception");
}
```

This time, the output will be simply `"Exception"`. Remember, you don't always have to catch exceptions in the same place where they're thrown.

If you still have questions about what might happen in a give case, create your own samples to test the case and see.

Comment: Thank you very much for the examples. I ran your first code sample. System didn't crash but it didn't give any error either. When I added the code "throw new DivideByZeroException();" in the try block, I got "Attempted to divide by zero" error message.

Comment: When I run the program without "throw new DivideByZeroException( );", program execution didn't enter the catch block. When I threw it explicitly, the catch block is called and the error message is displayed.

Comment: Check this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kuXq0R  Not sure why the last sample doesn't do anything.

Comment: Apologies for the persistence. Please check this out. It is the same code as yours but the catch block message is not displayed (doesn't even enter the catch block) https://dotnetfiddle.net/N67HJ4

Comment: I found it. For some reason, division by 0.0 (as opposed to the variable d, which was assigned a value of 0) is not throwing the exception. Don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

OP:

```
throw new IndexOutofRangeException;
```

This would **not** even compile(no brackets).

You should throw exceptions if something is *unexpected* in your domain and you should catch them in the place where you know how to *handle* them.

You wrote:

> "There is code in the try block that generates an exception but try block does not have throw statement. What will happen?".

The exception will bubble up the stack and your `catch` statement would execute if exception type and pattern matching corresponds to the thrown exception.

Comment: This is a different take than I got from the question... but I love it! Since the Q is older now, would you object if I adapted this as another example in my answer? If you feel like it's stealing your idea, I'll leave it alone.

Answer (score -1):

If code creates an exception but does not throw it, `try`/`catch` doesn't see it.  Throwing an exception is the only thing that makes an exception different from any other class type.

.NET exceptions are software artifacts.  Although many of them correspond to hardware traps or OS errors, the hardware does not produce, generate, or throw .NET exception objects.  What happens is that the other errors are being detected by code in the .NET runtime engine that then creates and throws a .NET exception object, translating the lower-level error information into properties on the .NET exception.

That translation/wrapping code may be invoked in an event-driven fashion, for example by installing a handler for Windows Structured Exception Handling, rather than having code to test every arithmetic result for floating-point NaNs.  But it still is software.  As a specific example, in Joel's answer, the code `1 / 0.0` does not generate a `DivideByZeroException`.  It generates an FPU exception, and the common language runtime handles that FPU exception.  It is the handler in the CLR that creates and throws the `DivideByZeroException` instance which lands in your `catch` block.